# How to find all files on a *NIX server containing a certain string

Tags: linux, grep, centos

I want to produce a list of every file on my server that contains a certain email address within the file. Starting with `htdocs` and all of its sub-directories.

I am using this command:

```
find /htdocs/ | xargs grep -n "myname@abc.com"
```

I seem to be getting the files that contain the string, but I am alos getting a listing of all directories, which I do not want in the list. I simply want the file containg the stirng to be returned.

Here are some of the results I do not want to see:

- `grep: /htdocs/live/abcdef/contact/facilities/GoogleCalendar/gphp/examples/templates: Is a directory`
- `grep: edited.jpg: No such file or directory`
- `grep: /htdocs/.pki/nssdb: Permission denied`

Comment: Something like: `grep -nsF 'myname@abc.com' -r /htdocs`? To follow symlinks use `-R` instead of `-r`.

Comment: Looks like that is working...thanks @randomir

Comment: I am getting a bit more than I want, although the list is significantly refined. I am getting `grep: /htdocs/.pki/nssdb: Permission denied` which I would like to not see as well. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, see my edit (add `-s`).

Comment: Looking much better @randomir ! That seems to be the answer. If you move it to an answer, I'll select it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` can recurse on a given directory if you use the `-r` or `-R` flag. The second one will follow all symbolic links. The `rgrep` is a shortcut for `grep -r`.

```
grep -nsF 'myname@abc.com' -R /htdocs
```

`-F` treats the pattern as a fixed string, and `-s` silences the output in case of unreadable or nonexisting files.